# Canvas positioning

Tags: css, canvas

I build a small app using Bootstrap 5. There are 10 columns col-lg-10 on the left and 2 columns col-lg-2 on the right on the desktop view. The canvas clock is to be located in the centre of the most right columns. At the moment the clock is not centred and any CSS I apply does not seem to work. Please see the HTML code:

'''

```
  <section>
      <div class="container-fluid">           
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mx-auto">
                <!-- analog clock location -->
                <div id="clockContainer">
                  <canvas id="analogClock"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

'''
I tried to centre the canvas clock using bootstrap classes. The class="mx-auto" class was applied                     on the div with an id="clockContainer". But this does seem to solve the problem.

Later, I linked the CSS file and tried to do the following (non of the below solution worked):

```
#clockContainer{
    margin: auto; 
    width: 250px;
}
#analogClock{
    width: 250px;
}
```

I tried also:

```
#clockContainer{
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Any hints on how to resolve it?
Thanks!

Comment: try to add `d-flex` to `#clockContainer` with `mx-auto`

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Are you trying to position the canvas or the drawing of the clock within the canvas? We need to see that I think.